# How to stop tracking AdRoll Pixel?

Tags: javascript, cookies, gdprconsentform

I'm using a cookie consent banner to start/stop tracking on a website. There were FB Pixel and Rakuten but now I need to add AdRoll Pixel to that list.

To start track FB Pixel I need to

```
export const enableTracking = () => {
  if (window.fbq) {
    window.fbq('consent', 'grant');
  }
};

export const disableTracking = () => {
  if (window.fbq) {
    window.fbq('consent', 'revoke');
  }
};
```

For Rakuten I use:

```
export const enableTracking = () => {
  window.__rmcp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
};

export const disableTracking = () => {
  if (rakutenLoaded) {
    window.__rmcp = [];
  }
};`
```

But I can't find any place in AdRoll's documentation on how to perform the same actions as I do for FB Pixel and Rakuten.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation at https://help.adroll.com/hc/en-us/articles/211846018-Introduction-to-Your-AdRoll-Pixel#view-your-pixel-0-0

If follow the steps there, especially step 3

> 3. If you haven't yet selected a cookie consent tool, choose one and click Save.

Then you can possibly read from the generated code that includes the cookie constent tool how they "invalidate" the consent on their end.

You can also roll your own implementation that is run before the adroll code is run.

```
export const enableTracking = () => {
   window.adroll_pix_id = "your pixel id"
};

export const disableTracking = () => {
  delete window.adroll_pix_id;

};
```